# SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) warns of an unresolved table reference, but the table exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

SSDT complains that within the code of a stored procedure, a referenced table does not exist. Warning SQL71502.

But the table *does* exist, and its definition is valid. The table is *not* in another database, and it even appears correctly in intellisense menus. This is a very straightforward, small database and the problem is just between a local stored procedure and a local table. Both scripts are set to Build.

How can I remove this invalid warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - sometimes you just have to step away for a bit. A pair of parentheses in the stored procedure was tripping up SSDT. It did not cause a build error or syntax error, but was confusing the parser somehow such that the name of the table could not be correctly linked to the definition of the table.