# Unresolved Reference To Index Despite Its Existence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I'm attempting to write a stored procedure that DROPs a columnstore index, the index-creation script does exist, the SSDT table designer for the table associated with the index in question does display the correct index, and yet Visual Studio is producing "Procedure: [dbo].[TestProcedure] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[TestTable].[TestIndex]". The 'Build Action' setting is set to build on all three files, and all objects are in the same schema. I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2015 With Update 3  and SSDT 14.0.6 **Is there any way to resolve the reference warning produced by the code below?**

I tried the solution proposed in this post, but it didn't resolve the issue: [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) warns of an unresolved table reference, but the table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309897/sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-warns-of-an-unresolved-table-reference-but-the-tab)

TestTable.sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]( [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY )
```

TestIndex.sql

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [TestIndex] 
ON [dbo].[TestTable]
```

TestProcedure.sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProcedure
AS
DROP INDEX TestIndex ON dbo.TestTable
```

Comment: Looks like an SSDT bug to me. The warning occurs with a columnstore index but not a traditional b-tree index. Consider submitting [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProcedure
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC('DROP INDEX IF EXISTS TestIndex ON dbo.TestTable');
END;
```

Alternatively adding `IF EXISTS` only:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProcedure
AS
BEGIN
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS TestIndex ON dbo.TestTable;
END;
```

Comment: While this would technically eliminate the reference warning, I want to retain the design-time and compile-time reference checks, and so I consider dynamic SQL to be a step in the wrong direction in this case. Question will be edited to reflect this.

Comment: @derekbaker783 Did you try a version with `BEGIN END`? `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProcedure
AS BEGIN
DROP INDEX TestIndex ON dbo.TestTable; END;`

Comment: When I add IF EXISTS, the reference warning is removed. Adding BEGIN and END makes no difference. If you edit the dynamic SQL out of your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @derekbaker783 Sure, Done. As for `BEGIN-AFTER` is a good practice to add them.